# change the source data in existing pivot table python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pivot-table

trying to update the source data in existing pivot table but i am not able to do it ,I am struggling from yesterday ,I tried by doing chnage pivotcache() but it is not happeing 
this is the piece of code which i am trying so far

```
excel_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app.Interactive = False
excel_app.Visible = False
excel_app.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\7\Desktop\o_P_Script\S_ext.xlsx')
ws = xlBook.Worksheets['Sheet2']
ws.Unprotect()  # IF protected
pivotCount = ws.PivotTables().Count
print("pivot count is",pivotCount

for j in range(1, pivotCount + 1):
    ws.PivotTables(j).PivotCache().Refresh()

# Put protection back on
#ws.Protect(DrawingObjects=True, Contents=True, Scenarios=True, AllowUsingPivotTables=True)
xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=1)

del xlBook

excel_app.Quit()
del excel_app
```

or how can i change this to to python code

```
Sub ChangePivotSourceData()

Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MyData")
Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: i am struggling in this ,

Comment: an y help on this